# Как в PyQt5 правильно прописать недостающий атрибут?

Tags: pyqt5

Данный код работает до тех пор, пока не вызывается функция  **ledControl()**. Выходит сообщение: **AttributeError: 'New' object has no attribute 'serialSend'**. Как правильно прописать этот атрибут?

***main.py***

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5.QtSerialPort import QSerialPort, QSerialPortInfo
from PyQt5.QtCore import QIODevice


class New(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(New, self).__init__()

        loadUi("Arduino_GUI.ui", self)
        self.setWindowTitle('New')

        self.openB.clicked.connect(self.onOpen)
        self.closeB.clicked.connect(self.onClose)
        self.ledC.stateChanged.connect(self.ledControl)

        self.serial = QSerialPort()
        self.serial.setBaudRate(115200)
        portList = []
        ports = QSerialPortInfo().availablePorts()
        for port in ports:
            portList.append(port.portName())
        print(portList)
        self.comL.addItems(portList)

    def onOpen(self):
        print('on')
        self.serial.setPortName(self.comL.currentText())
        self.serial.open(QIODevice.ReadWrite)

    def onClose(self):
        print('close')
        self.serial.close()

    def ledControl(self, val):
        if val == 2: val = 1;
        print('led')
        self.serialSend([0, val])

    def closeEvent(self, e):
        super().closeEvent(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = New()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

Элементарная невнимательность. Вопрос закрыт

***main.py***

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5.QtSerialPort import QSerialPort, QSerialPortInfo
from PyQt5.QtCore import QIODevice


class New(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(New, self).__init__()

        loadUi("Arduino_GUI.ui", self)
        self.setWindowTitle('New')

        self.openB.clicked.connect(self.onOpen)
        self.closeB.clicked.connect(self.onClose)
        self.ledC.stateChanged.connect(self.ledControl)

        self.serial = QSerialPort()
        self.serial.setBaudRate(115200)
        portList = []
        ports = QSerialPortInfo().availablePorts()
        for port in ports:
            portList.append(port.portName())
        print(portList)
        self.comL.addItems(portList)

    def onOpen(self):
        print('on')
        self.serial.setPortName(self.comL.currentText())
        self.serial.open(QIODevice.ReadWrite)

    def onClose(self):
        print('close')
        self.serial.close()

    def serialSend(self, data):
        txs = ''
        for val in data:
            txs += str(val)
            txs += ','
        txs = txs[:-1]
        txs += ';'
        self.serial.write(txs.encode())

    def ledControl(self, val):
        if val == 2: val = 1;
        print('led')
        self.serialSend([0, val])

    def closeEvent(self, e):
        super().closeEvent(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = New()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```